# how to add a tab sort of spacing in front of a fresh java line

Tags: java

This is the Question

[image: This is the Question]

This is what i could came up with

[image: This is what i could came up with]

My work still needs a tab like spacing before the author's name. Please help me add that space before the author's name. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the tab separator (`\t`):

```
System.out.println("\tKobayashi Issa (1763-1827)");
```

If you are printing with a monospaced font, then you could also just include the number of desired spaces:

```
System.out.println("        Kobayashi Issa (1763-1827)");
```

Comment: Thanks a lot mate. You are the man. I'll mark your question as answered in 10 minutes!

Comment: Or you can add a variable number of spacing using printf: `System.out.printf("%10s", "String")`